# CECIL getting the TypeRef of a GenericArg of a class implementing a generic interface (eg ICollection)

Tags: c#, .net, mono.cecil

**Note**: beware, this is a `Mono.Cecil` specific question, not a question of `System.Reflection`.

Exploring a `Cecil.ModuleDefinition` one can get the list of all implemented `TypeReference`s. It is known that some of these types will implement (maybe indirectly) `ICollection<some_type>`.
**The problem**:

1. list all the `TypeReference`s in the module that implement (directly or indirectly) `ICollection`
2. given one such `TypeReference` extract the `TypeReference` corresponding to the Generic Argument used in implementing the `ICollection`.

The "cookie crumbles" when the source `TypeReference` points to a *fully specified* type (i.e. the type is known in full) but not a *fully defined* type (i.e. there's no class or struct which "embodies" the type). The easier way to demonstrate is by trying to solve the original problem starting from a `TypeReference` which happens to be the type of a field or property:

```cs
// "probed" code
class Foo
{
}

class Baz
{
    public List<Foo> boz { get; set;  }
}
```

Then "probing code" using Cecil, attempting to solve the problem of

> "What is the element type for the `Baz.boz` property, as seen by using the `TypeArgument` of the `ICollection` interface implemented by the `typeof(Baz.boz)`?":

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ModuleDefinition module = ModuleDefinition.ReadModule(@"Probed.exe");
        module.ReadSymbols();

        TypeDefinition bazClass = module.Types.FirstOrDefault(e =>
            e.FullName.EndsWith("Baz") // don't care about namespace, there only 1 Baz
        );
        // The 'property type' is the type of the GetMethod for the property
        TypeReference bozPropTypeRef = bazClass.Properties.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name == "boz").GetMethod.ReturnType;
        // Let's try to resolve the TypeReference to a TypeDefinition
        // to be able to access the Interfaces
        TypeDefinition bozPropTypeDef = bozPropTypeRef.Resolve();
        foreach(var iface in bozPropTypeDef.Interfaces)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Full iface name {0}", iface.FullName);
            /// Big bada-boom! The TypeArgument of the generic interfaces
            /// is wiped out
        }
    }
}
```

The output of the probing app is:

```
Full iface name System.Collections.Generic.IList`1<T>
Full iface name System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1<T>
Full iface name System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<T>
Full iface name System.Collections.IEnumerable
Full iface name System.Collections.IList
Full iface name System.Collections.ICollection
Full iface name System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyList`1<T>
Full iface name System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyCollection`1<T>
```

No `<Foo>` there, only a `<T>` that points nowhere.

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit late response, but for future reference:

A **TypeDefinition** will never contain *type arguments*, instead, it will have a list of **type parameters**.

`List<string>` is represented in Mono.Cecil as a `GenericInstanceType` so you could use some code like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Mono.Cecil;

namespace testgen
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using var a = AssemblyDefinition.ReadAssembly(typeof(Program).Assembly.Location);
            var prop = a.MainModule.Types.Single(t => t.Name == "Program").Properties.Single(p => p.Name == "Prop");

            var propType = (GenericInstanceType) prop.PropertyType;
            System.Console.WriteLine(propType.GenericArguments[0].FullName);
        }

        List<string> Prop {get; set; }
    }
}
```